# I dropped my computer on the floor and now it won't boot. Why is this happening?

Tags: boot

A couple of days ago I started up my computer and for some reason, I would press the power button, the computer would power up and the fan would make the same noise as usual. Except, normally, it would slow down after about 5-10 seconds. However, the loud noise of the fan was persistent and wouldn't stop.

Furthermore, the OS wasn't starting and my screen remained blank. So I hoovered over the grills covering the fan to clear out the dust, which miraculously worked. However, today I am having the same issue.

This time however, I was the cause, as I dropped the computer on the floor and now the fan makes the loud noise when I power up the computer and the OS doesn't start.

Could you please tell me what the issue could be? My computer is a Dell vostro 200 slim with a Vista OS.

Comment: The first time it was having problems was probably because it was overheating. When you vacuumed it, you cleaned out the dust and the suction cooled it down. After dropping it, the problem should be obvious: you broke it. Do you see the BIOS data, logo, or *anything* when turning it on now?

Comment: Dropping it could have done any number of things. You could have dislodged something that does not allow it to POST. You could have cracked something that does not allow it to POST. You could have damaged the HDD, in which case it will POST, but won't go much further.

Comment: How high was the drop? Dropping a laptop from even a foot at the right angle on the right surface can seriously damage the hard drive, screen, and/or other components. (A moment for my 2005 ThinkPad R51. You held me together like concrete, until you fell on that concrete... \*sniff\*)

Comment: The drop was not that high, the thing that's unusual is that it is doing the exact same things as it was a few days ago

Comment: And synetech there is nothing showwing as was nothing showing when the computer previously broke down

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons for a system not booting after one has dropped it, in order of least likely to most likely:

- Component dislodged from motherboard due to impact.  Items to suspect in order are: RAM, CPU or case fan, expansion/graphics card, SATA cable, or possibly a jumper on the motherboard may have gotten loose.
- Component damaged due to stress induced by attached cord pulling (i.e. VGA socket may be damaged if the fall caused a cable to pull on it too hard).
- CPU worked loose due to impact and isn't fully making contact with board socket, or board socket has been damaged.
- Component damaged due to impact.  Items to suspect in order are: hard drive, daughterboard component along side containing USB or audio ports, power switch, power supply, motherboard or plugin-component such as RAM or motherboard.

Comment: [Teardown Guide](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/02/28/inside-dell-vostro-200-slim-tower.html) for that model. If the site is down, here is a [way back machine cache](http://web.archive.org/web/20110615073958/http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/02/28/inside-dell-vostro-200-slim-tower.html). Opening it up and inspecting it should be the very first thing you do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a few things I'd do. Your video card issues sound VERY much like the [issues i had with the mini tower version](https://superuser.com/questions/333617/is-it-normal-for-a-dell-inspiron-530-to-have-is-fan-to-spin-up-3-times-before-i) of what i believe is a system of the same era. If its got a Nvidia graphics card card, its probably that.

[Open up the system](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/02/28/inside-dell-vostro-200-slim-tower.html), unplug and replugin everything. Remove the video card, and the small back cover over the blue panel - there's a VGA connector for the onboard video card - test to see if that works. If not, go for a minimal setup (one stick of ram and power) to see what it does.

Shockingly enough, I've seen desktops run perfectly after being dropped off a desk, even if my first guess is that being dropped off the desk messed something up.