# How can I test my GPU memory/RAM?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, gpu, cuda, opencl

I run `MemTest86` a lot at work on customer's machines, and it's great for troubleshooting memory issues. My question is, how can I test that a GPU is starting to go?

I know of programs like 3DMark to push the graphics card to its limits, but what about with Video Memory? Is it worth testing? Is there a stress tool actually able to catch issues in the video card (memory), perhaps using CUDA/OpenCL?

Comment: (in my opinion) I think a stress test would do the trick, because if it is going bad it would either fail or not meet the benchmarks for that kind of card - but, if anyone can find a utility for this, I would be interested as well.

Comment: @ekaj I actually just had a customer's computer in with 2 GTX670s in SLI, and it passed the benchmarks, but still kept freezing the computer when just running every day applications like IE9 and Microsoft Word. When I switched out just ONE of the cards, the pair worked great

Comment: That's really weird - afterwards, did you separately test that card in a different computer?

Comment: No, we gave the customer back one of his working cards and a new one off the shelf that wouldn't crash. We will be testing the other one in a new system, but need a big one first to handle it

Comment: @Luke - I always test the cards individually for just this reason, and that approach has worked pretty well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Warning:** This GPU stress test method may not be suitable for newer graphics cards. It is primarily designed for older hardware that have less than 1GB of VRAM .

GPU stress tests are generally designed to attempt to overheat the GPU. Depending on the particular test, this might or might not use the entire video memory or check its integrity at some point.

[Video Memory stress Test](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/video_memory_stress_test.html) is specifically designed for this purpose, and it's quite similar to MemTest86+. You can test the memory using DirectX, CUDA, or OpenGL.

The downloadable zip contains VMT (for Windows) and VMTCE (Clean Environment, bootable ISO). There's also a floppy version.

#### Screenshots

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is also http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/ which I use under Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: How to make it work with GTX 660? I'm getting error ----- Trying 32bpp RGB:888 mode...OK
PATTERN NOT FOUND
Trying 32bpp BGR:888 mode...NOT SUPPORTED (Code: 80004001)
NO PASS COMPLETED

Comment: @Hooch: Did you try different test types? I'd expect DirectX and/or CUDA to work. If neither does, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Seems like this limits out at 2GB video memory... or is my card messed up?

Comment: Does anyone have a grub2 config for booting the ISO version of this?

Comment: One of the few times a software-rec comes good, congratz.