# GPU chip is not working and sometimes showing worst graphics

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

This is screenshot has been taken, when my video card was working properly

[image]

And this screenshot has been taken today (having problem with my video card)

[image]

So, anyone let me know, if you could figure it out, what could happened with my video card. In first screenshot you can see GPU temperature showing whereas in second screenshot it is not listed.

And, I took this screenshot from Device Manager, to let you know about my Video Card and its status.

[image]

And, sometimes my system shows 6 screens or even it looks like 8-bit system, where I get very worst graphics. And, suddenly, it works fine (when I restart my system). I went to nearest service center and they are charging for more than $160 to replace my 256 MB graphics card. So, anyone help me, what should I do ?

Comment: About the pictures, I can say that the temperature sensor in the graphics board is damaged or SpeedFan is not working properly or reading the correct info.
A 256MB graphics board seems dated so I would recommend replacing it. Unless you state what kind of graphical problems you have other than this, we can't debug your problem.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: I have updated my screenshot by including video card status into it. Please see and let me know what do you think now ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the 8000 series of GPUs were a little problematic, and while competent performers, tended to die early deaths, whether [desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/333617/is-it-normal-for-a-dell-inspiron-530-to-have-is-fan-to-spin-up-3-times-before-i/333980#333980) or laptops with specific models. Some even had extended warranties or were swapped out - for example, [dell extended their warranty](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/direct2dell/b/direct2dell/archive/2008/09/12/nvidia-gpu-update-limited-warranty-enhancement-details.aspx), and there was even a c[lass action lawsuit](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security-central/lawsuit-claims-nvidia-hid-serious-flaw-in-graphics-chips-439).

The issue you have might be with drivers, click on the ! and see what the exact issue is.

That said there's a good chance your video card is dying, and most of the fixes are odd - anandtech seems to think a [hairdryer](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6840/hardware-tricks-can-you-fix-a-failing-mobile-gpu-with-a-hair-dryer) to the chip will work, and some people have baked [graphics cards](http://forum.notebookreview.com/gaming-software-graphics-cards/498554-8800m-gtx-problem-after-baking.html). YMMV, and naturally this is a last resort. A better safer bet, is to assume your system will fail any moment, and work accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The service center is probably correct. Your GPU is probably suffering from [bump underfill cracking](http://electronicdesign.com/digital-ics/repeating-failed-history-fails-designs). The solution is, unfortunately, to replace the motherboard.

As you use the laptop, the GPU gets hotter and cooler. As this happens, the components that connect the GPU to the motherboard expand and contract at different rates. Eventually, the underfill (the material that connects the chip carrier to the solder bumps that connect it to the motherboard) develops cracks. These cracks cause the connections between the GPU and motherboard to become intermittent.

As it first starts to happen, the connection is worst when the GPU is cool. As the GPU heats up, the underfill expands and fills the cracks, and things work better. But eventually it cracks enough that some connections are lost entirely and the GPU is no longer usable. As you noticed, the hotter your GPU is, the better it works. This is a very typical symptom with this problem.

Comment: When you say motherboard you mean graphics board, right?

Comment: There is no graphics board in your laptop. There is just a motherboard that include a CPU and GPU.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz agree, but when I told them to replace my motherboard, then they start suggesting me that, **instead of replacing new motherboard, better you would purchase new laptop, because motherboard will cost you around $300+**. And, that's why I'm confuse, what to do ?

Comment: If the laptop is worth $300, replace the motherboard. If not, or if you want a new laptop anyway, get a new laptop.